# Error installing emacs24

Tags: emacs24.4

I'm on ubuntu 14.04 64 bit, I had emacs 23 working great, I removed it to install emacs 24 and I get this error

```
emacs
X protocol error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) on protocol request 139
When compiled with GTK, Emacs cannot recover from X disconnects.
This is a GTK bug: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85715
For details, see etc/PROBLEMS.

(emacs:776): GLib-WARNING **: g_main_context_prepare() called recursively from within a source's check() or prepare() member.

(emacs:776): GLib-WARNING **: g_main_context_check() called recursively from within a source's check() or prepare() member.
Fatal error 6: Aborted
Backtrace:
emacs[0x4f74cb]
emacs[0x4dcf3e]
emacs[0x4f7513]
emacs[0x4b219b]
emacs[0x4b420c]
emacs[0x4b426d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(_XError+0x12b)[0x7f2ade76854b]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(+0x3b5e7)[0x7f2ade7655e7]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(+0x3b695)[0x7f2ade765695]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(_XEventsQueued+0x55)[0x7f2ade765fc5]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(XPending+0x4d)[0x7f2ade75812d]
...
[1]    776 abort (core dumped)  emacs
```

So it crashes every time I try to start it

Comment: Are you trying to install from source, or are you using `apt-get`?

Comment: @Dan from ubuntu software center - tried with apt-get too